# more than one form with the same input ID send just the first value with Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am doing ajax function to do insert into DB using form and input type=hidden but when I put more than form in the same page it is always take just the first value in the first form

here is the code:

the Ajax function

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   //Browser Support Code
   function ajaxFunction(){
      var ajaxRequest; // The variable that makes Ajax possible!  
      try{
         // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
         ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } catch (e){
         // Internet Explorer Browsers
         try{
             ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
             } catch (e) {
                try{
                   ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e){
                  // Something went wrong
                  alert("Your browser broke!");
                  return false;
                }
            }
       }
       // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
       ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
       if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
          var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById("ajaxDiv");
          ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
       }
    }
    var in1 = document.getElementById("in1").value;
    var queryString1 = "?in1=" + in1;

    //ajaxRequest.open("GET", "/sites/all/php/check.php" + queryString, true);
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "/sites/all/php/check.php" + queryString1, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
}
//–>
</script>
```

here is the html forms

```
    <form name="myForm1">
         <input type="hidden" value="1" id="in1">
         <a onclick="ajaxFunction()" class="folloo"></a> 
         <form name="myForm2">
               <input type="hidden" value="2" id="in1">
               <a onclick="ajaxFunction()" class="folloo"></a> 
               <form name="myForm3">
                     <input type="hidden" value="3" id="in1">
                     <a onclick="ajaxFunction()" class="folloo"></a>
               </form>
         </form>
   </form>
```

and here is the check.php code that do the DB query

```
<?php
   //Connect to MySQL Server
   //connect to your database ** EDIT REQUIRED HERE **
   mysql_connect("localhost","admin","123456") or die('Cannot connect to the database
                 because: ' . mysql_error());

   //specify database ** EDIT REQUIRED HERE **
   mysql_select_db("dbname") or die("Unable to select database"); 
   //select which database we're using

   // Retrieve data from Query String
   $in1 = $_GET['in1'];

   // Escape User Input to help prevent SQL Injection
   $in1 = mysql_real_escape_string($in1);

   //Build and run a SQL Query on our MySQL tutorial
   if($in1){
       mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (name)
                  VALUES ('" . $in1. "')");
   }

?>
```

put when i click on any link it is always send the first value.

cah anyone tell mewhat is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

`id` values [**must be unique on the page**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute). You've shown that you have multiple `input type="hidden"` elements with the same `id` value (`"in1"`). If you have more than one element with the same `id` value, when you try to look it up (for instance, using `getElementById`), most browsers will give you the first one, but it's undefined behavior because the markup/DOM is *invalid*.

The fix is to fix the IDs so that they're unique, or not use IDs at all and use something that *isn't* required to be unique, such as `name` or `class` — but then you'll need to retrieve it with `querySelectorAll` or similar, and deal with the fact that you have multiple matching elements.

Comment: document.getElementsByName("").value return undefined value

Comment: @ManMann: `getElementsByName` returns **elements**, plural, in the form of a `NodeList`. `value` is a property of *individual* elements. (Also, I assume you're not passing an empty string into it as you've shown above?) If you give it a string with the name of the elements, and then look at the resulting list's `length`, and index into it with `[0]`, `[1]`, etc., you should be able to find the `value` property on each of those.

Comment: : I did the changes but still return undefined value :(

Comment: can I change it to jquery function??

Comment: @ManMann: *"I did the changes but still return undefined value"* Works for me: [Example](http://jsbin.com/ajubaq) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ajubaq). *"can I change it to jquery function"* Of course: [Example](http://jsbin.com/ajubaq/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ajubaq/2/edit)